# Inconsistent JSON Decoding Results in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I'm facing a perplexing issue with JSON data in Flutter. When I attempt to decode and print a specific part of my JSON data (like the city's name), everything is ok. However, when I expand this to print the entire JSON map, things become inconsistent.

This segment of the code operates flawlessly:

```
     getData().then((value) {
    var map=jsonDecode(value!); ///////////tthis works !!!
    print(map['name']);
});
```

when I take the output from the console and paste it into a JSON beautifier website, I receive an error stating that the JSON format is invalid.

this code:

```
getData().then((value) {
    var map=jsonDecode(value!);
    print(map);
});
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? How might I address this inconsistency and the "invalid format" error from the beautifier site?

Edit

```
{"coord":{"lon":35.2881,"lat":36.985},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":290.16,"feels_like":290.06,"temp_min":290.16,"temp_max":290.44,"pressure":1018,"humidity":82},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.06,"deg":280},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1696472393,"sys":{"type":1,"id":6946,"country":"TR","sunrise":1696477017,"sunset":1696519060},"timezone":10800,"id":325361,"name":"Adana Province","cod":200}
```

Comment: Could you show the log response? (hide any potential sensitive information). Mostly to see the error you're getting.

Comment: thank for replying I have edited my question

Comment: Uh, print the `value` and not the `map` if you are interested in the JSON text?

Comment: The example from your edit is valid JSON. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: You are right ..I am sory my mistake.I am a beginner.I just realized my mistake

Comment: @flutterapp if you've solved your problem, either post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you think the answer might help other people, or just delete the question, as it will be closed as non-reproducible otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` itself already a json I think, you can directly print the `value` insted of the `map`

```
getData().then((value) {
    var map=jsonDecode(value!);
    print(map);  // not this
    print(value);  // try this
});
```